# Visual Studio Project Properties

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-standard

This is what I normally see when I view Properties on a project in VS 2017:

[image]
Instead, this is what I see:

[image]

**Edit:** The problem seemed to be at the solution level. Removing and adding the project fixed it. The diff in the solution ended up being this:

[image]

Comment: You are missing the project file it looks like

Comment: What do you mean? The csproj file is a part of the solution. Otherwise , it wouldn't show up.

Comment: Well your second image is cropped out so I can't see it. If you are using source control right click on project and reload/exclude/re-include project. Also if not added do a git add

Comment: It's cropped because the rest of the screen is superfluous. What I should be seeing is the top image, but what I see is the bottom image.

Comment: Are you sure you are right clicking on the project file? It looks like the Solution file dialog.

Comment: @aguertin, removing the project and re-adding it fixed the problem. You should suggest this and I will mark it as the answer

Comment: Ok, I added it to answer. The second option should work to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPTION 1: 
Unload the project by right-clicking and selecting "unload project" then reload the project by doing the opposite.

OPTION 2:
Close Visual Studio. ensure devenv.exe  isn't in task manager
Delete %USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache directory
Restart Visual Studio

Comment: See the diff in opening post for what this changed in the solution file.

Comment: That should be fine, it's just putting a new GUID correct